# Why is my calculated column empty (it uses a hashtable lookup)

Tags: powershell

Why is the LicenseStatusText column empty in the output of this code?

```
$statusLookup=@{0='Unlicensed'; 1='Licensed'; 2='OOBGrace'; 3='OOTGrace'; 4='NonGenuineGrace'; 5='Notification'; 6='ExtendedGrace'}
Get-CimInstance SoftwareLicensingProduct -Filter "Name like 'Windows%'" | where { $_.PartialProductKey } |
     select Description, LicenseStatus, @{N='LicenseStatusText';E={$statusLookup[$_.LicenseStatus]}}
```

I have also tried to wrap the hashtable-keys in '

When I use `E={$_.LicenseStatus}` LicenseStatusText output is **1**

Comment: @Itchydon thanks for testing - after your reply, I tried two more machines (posh 5.1 and 7.0) - no luck. When you modify the select to "select  {$_.LicenseStatus.Gettype()}" : is the type of LicenseStatus "UInt32"?

Comment: Cast your key to `Int32` --> `@{N='LicenseStatusText';E={$statusLookup[[int]$_.LicenseStatus]}}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integers (within the -2^32 to 2^32 range) that are not cast or are unquoted are coerced into the `Int32` value type. This happens when creating a hash table entry `@{0='something'}` where `0` is `Int32`. Since the value provided by the `LicenseStatus` property is `Uint32`, your key types are not matching. You need to force the issue by either casting in the hash table or in the calculated property.

```
# Casting in calculated property
$statusLookup=@{0='Unlicensed'; 1='Licensed'; 2='OOBGrace'; 3='OOTGrace'; 4='NonGenuineGrace'; 5='Notification'; 6='ExtendedGrace'}
Get-CimInstance SoftwareLicensingProduct -Filter "Name like 'Windows%'" | where { $_.PartialProductKey } |
     select Description, LicenseStatus, @{N='LicenseStatusText';E={$statusLookup[[int]$_.LicenseStatus]}}

# Casting in hash table
$statusLookup=@{[uint32]0='Unlicensed'; [uint32]1='Licensed'; [uint32]2='OOBGrace'; [uint32]3='OOTGrace'; [uint32]4='NonGenuineGrace'; [uint32]5='Notification'; [uint32]6='ExtendedGrace'}
Get-CimInstance SoftwareLicensingProduct -Filter "Name like 'Windows%'" | where { $_.PartialProductKey } |
     select Description, LicenseStatus, @{N='LicenseStatusText';E={$statusLookup[$_.LicenseStatus]}}
```

Comment: Ah, I see - so my other idea to use '0', '1' ... as keys does work, too - if I use $_.LicenseStatus.ToString() - Thanks for your help.